# How to disable windows 7 taskbar thumbnails preview?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I do not like the taskbar thumbnails, how could I disable it?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answer, but what I need is a preview like this while mouse hover on the taskbar(which is retrieved by using windows 7 basic theme/setting) while using the standard(non-basic) theme.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, Only way you can do that is by disabling Aero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) allows you to do this. The most recent version includes four hover options:

1. Default Windows 7 behavior
2. List
3. Tooltip
4. Nothing

[image]

Comment: Actually, it only allows you to have nothing at all happen when hovering.