# Win 7 - Taskbar preview does not appear

Tags: windows-7, performance, taskbar, window-manager, dwm

Machine information

- Windows 7 Enterprise x64
- HP Compaq 6300 Pro SFF

Preface - I have recently performed a full reimage on this machine. Reinstalled Windows from my company's base SCCM image about a week ago.

Issue as described: User expects small preview window to appear on hovering over pinned or open taskbar icon. Only thing that appears is a list of the names of the current windows open.

[image: example]

Troubleshooting steps performed:

- switched to Windows Classic mode and back to Aero default
- Rated Windows Experience Index (1.0 score)
- Cycled between all 3 performance options (Adjust for appearance, Adjust for performance and Let windows choose).
- Tried enabling ONLY "Animations in the Taskbar".
- Editing hover-time value in HKCU registry entry
- confirmed DWM enabled in Services. Restarted anyway as a test.
- checked for `NumThumbnails` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`, no matching registry entry was found.
- modified "Taskbar button combining" options in Toolbar properties. tried all 3 options.

Nothing I have done seems to resolve the issue. I doubt reinstalling Windows would be a good option since I've already done this not very long ago to troubleshoot another unrelated issue.

Comment: Are you sure this hasn't been purposefully disabled in the image you have used?

Comment: [Make](https://superuser.com/questions/202843/how-to-disable-windows-7-taskbar-thumbnails-preview?rq=1) sure it's enabled and currently has the setting you want it to have.

Comment: @Ramhound, I know it works in the image since I have it working on my own machine. I suspect it might have something to do with the WEI score of 1.0 for Aero performance. I discussed this with the user and she felt comfortable dealing with this issue for now until her refresh very soon.

Comment: this window is only shown when aero is one, you use aero basic. look which value causes winsat score of 1.